# Total N patients for precision around a rate, with varying FU times

Tags: panel-data, sample-size, statistical-power, poisson-process, incidence

To design a retrospective longitudinal study (outcome: certain event after drug exposure), we know that the annualized rate of that event is 0.06%, aka 0.0006/person-year (possibly underestimated as they only counted the first event for a given patient). I need to reproduce the study and calculate a sample size. With the R- package “presize”, giving a rate of 0.0006 and a width of 0.0015, we obtain that we’d need 4 events and total time=5741 (years). If we had information about the typical distribution for FU (exposure on drug) times, like 15% for example whose time is 0-0.5 years, 25% whose mean time is 0.5-1 years and the rest of patients moves in the range of 1-2 years; should we just here take the weighted mean and divide 5741/weighted mean to get the sample size?

Comment: I suspect something is missing in your power analysis.  To assess adequately the relationship between some predictor(s) and your outcome, I think you would need far more than 4 events.

Comment: hello, i do not want to perform a regression, just, for descriptive purposes, to detect a rate with a given precision. The question is more towards if after obtaining number of events and total time needed, if my weighted mean approach makes sense, thanks!